# Cannot use dynamic_cast to convert from Base to Derived

Tags: c++, polymorphism, game-engine, dynamic-cast

I get an error when I try to cast base class to derived class.
I want to access the derived classes that I have put in my components vector.

//Base and Derived

```
class Component
{
public:
    Component();
    virtual ~Component();
private:
};

class Material:public Component{...};
```

//in main

```
int textureID = gameScene.gameObjects[0].getComponent<Material>()->texture;
```

//game object

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "Component.h"

class GameObject:public Component
{
public:
    GameObject();
    GameObject(int otherAssetID);
    ~GameObject();

    int assetID;
    std::vector<Component> components;

    void addComponent(Component otherComponent);
    void deleteComponent(Component otherComponent);

    template <class T>
    T* getComponent() {
        for (int i = 0; i < components.size(); i++)
        {
            if (dynamic_cast<T*>(components[i]) != nullptr)
            {
                T *test = dynamic_cast<T*>(components[i]);
                return test;
            }
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
private:

};
```

Comment: hold pointers of base class in the vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vector<Component>` can not contain objects of class other than `Component` itself. If you add a `Material` object to the vector, the `Component` part of the `Material` will be stored. That problem is known as the [object slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

You probably want to make a vector holding pointers to the base polymorphic class.

```
::std::vector<::std::unique_ptr<Componenet>> components;
```

also `dynamic_cast` is expensive so you may want to call it only once storing returned value:

```
 T * const test = dynamic_cast<T*>(components[i].get());
 if(test)
 {
     return test;
 }
```